# Cheapest GPS that is accurate to ca. 30cm in woodland

Tags: gps

As part of my PhD field work it would be useful to have latitude/longitude measurements for the locations of ant nests that I am working on. These ant nests can be as close as 50cm together so the accuracy of the system would (I think) need to be higher than is available from a phone or basic GPS system. Does anyone know what system would be best for getting this sort of accuracy? My budget is probably only around £200. If it isn't possible in that price range it would be good to know what system I would need to use so that I can see if I can just borrow such a system.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try to look for dual GPS recievers. These enhance the precision of GPS, but I doubt that it will be as precise as your spec. Would fit your budget though...

Comment: OK great, I'll have a look at that then!

Comment: You can get sub-metre precision from an [SBAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNSS_augmentation) receiver, but you'll need line-of-sight visibility to the SBAS satellite for your area of the world.

Comment: UBlox [C94-M8P RTK kit](https://shop-emea.u-blox.com/en/eur/3~322~EMEA/Evaluation-kits-tools/Application-boards/C94-M8P-RTK-application-board) dual-receiver promises 2-cm precision using a fixed and a rover GPS that communicate over UHF. It's 359€.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you are going to look into Chen at al 2015
"Computationally efficient carrier integer ambiguity resolution in multiepoch gps/ins: a common-position-shift approach"
This is a very good paper, which allows location down to a centimeter level.
Anyway this approach is not plug and play, I fear you have to implement it on your own.
I'm not aware of any open source implementation so far.
More over if you are trying to locate the ants within a forest, then gps is a not the best approach. Gps uses some wavelengths which are absorbed easily by water and well the trees do contain at lot of water. Long story told short: gps in the forest will never be as accurate as you need.

I know this is not the answer you expected, hope it can help a bit

Comment: OK I guess that won't work very well then. Thanks a lot for your help!